# assembly combine 2 hex values into one

Tags: assembly, hex, bit-shift

I'm currently learning assembly, and am stuck on a problem. I need to convert 0x006B to 0xF06B.
The 'template' for a character in video memory is 0xTextcolor(white)-bgColor(black)-charactercode(6B).
I think my best bet is bit-shifting? Although I'm not at all familiar with it. Just started learning assembly yesterday.

EDIT:

First of all thanks for the replies, I figured it out. I'm using the 0x10c dev kit, which if I'm not mistaken emulates a DCPU-16 cpu. What I needed to do was (this code is part of a loop)

```
    set a, [text+i]
    set b, 0xf000
    bor a, b
    set [0x8000+i], a ;Put the data in the video memory
```

Where 'a' is the current character read in a 0x00XX format. And 'bor' is the '|' operation which Tobias pointed out.

Comment: Add `0xF000` and `0x006B`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what assembler you use, but you have to or 0x06B with 0xF00:

```
0x06B | 0xF00
```

How this is done depends on your assembly ..

Answer (score 0):

```
set a, [text+i]
and a, 0x00FF
bor a, 0xf000
set [0x8000+i], a ;Put the data in the video memory
```

Why ? `set a, [xxxx]` would read a **WORD**, not a BYTE, so if your text isn't unpacked or contains color attributes, you would get junk on the MSB that defines the color attributes. 
As an extra, you can simply add OR your desired attributes directly. You not need to waste a register to do that.

Even you can avoid using any register (except I) :

```
set [0x8000+i], [text+i]
and [0x8000+i], 0x00FF
bor [0x8000+i], 0xf000
```

However this code probably would use more space on RAM and perhaps is a few cycles slower.